# I have an image(.png) with random white patches on it. I want to fill those white patches with the nearest color of the image

Tags: r, rstudio

I have an image with white patches on it. I want to fill those patches using the nearest colour of the image using R.

Comment: In order for this to be answerable, you need to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and include what steps you've already taken to solve your problem.

Comment: I notice you do not have any R packages tagged. I'd recommend looking at image manipulation packages, such as 'magick', to see what is truly required for what you are asking.